# Add data attribute to wp_nav_menu

Tags: php, wordpress, menu, nav, custom-data-attribute

I have the following code:

```
$nav_menu_args = array('fallback_cb' => '','menu' => 'menu', 'menu_class' => 'menu_class');

$x = wp_nav_menu( apply_filters( 'widget_nav_menu_args', $nav_menu_args, 'menu', $args ) );

$pattern = '#<ul([^>]*)>#i'; 

$replacement = '<ul$1 data-attr="abc">';  // this is a wrong

echo preg_replace( $pattern, $replacement, $x );
```

I am trying to add a `data-attr` to `ul` by altering the pattern, and without making changes through `Walker_Nav_Menu`.

What I want to do is to have a list like this:

```
<ul class="menu_class" data-attr="abc">
  <li><li>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
  <li>
</ul>
```

But I get also a `data-attr` on my inner ul like this.

```
<ul class="menu_class" data-attr="abc">
  <li><li>
  <li>
    <ul data-attr="abc">
      <li></li>
    </ul>
  <li>
</ul>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Is the problem that it also adds a data-attr to the inner ul ?

Comment: Yes. I want to add data-attr to the ul.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I managed to solve this issue through $nav_menu_args.

Comment: You mean like what I just edited in my answer? Otherwise answer your own question with the solution and mark it as correct so other people can find the same solution.

Answer (score 11):

You could add the number of objects you want to replace so it only takes the first `ul`.

```
echo preg_replace( $pattern, $replacement, $x, 1 ); // 1 at the end to replace only the first occurence
```

Or just change the items_wrap key of the wp_nav_menu.

```
$nav_menu_args = array('fallback_cb' => '','menu' => 'menu', 'items_wrap' => '<ul class="menu_class" data-attr="abc">%3$s</ul>');
```

Comment: 'Had completely forgot about `items_wrap` - awesome!